# Bootstrap navbar JSF <h:commandLink> styling does not work

Tags: css, forms, jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3, anchor

I am using a navbar theme from Bootstrap. The navbar uses `<a>` to navigate to other pages. But i want to navigate by actions so that i can manage my views in the faces-config.xml. The navigation works already with the `<h:commandLink>`

But now the Problem: `<h:commandLink>` can only be used into `<h:form>` so everything will be renderd to a `<form>` and because of this all my CSS from bootstrap does not work anymore.

In my example the `<a>` are styled by CSS while the `<h:commandLink>` is not styled and out of position.

```
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Home.xhtml">MyFacebook</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Home.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Posts.xhtml">Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Login.xhtml">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Register.xhtml">Registrierung</a></li>
                    <li> 
                        <h:form![enter image description here][1]>
                            <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}" rendered="#{loginBean.loggedIn}"></h:commandLink>
                        </h:form> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem why Bootstrap's styles don't work is that Bootstrap uses following selectors for example for `<a/>` in the navbar.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #777;
    /* other styles */
}
```

In order to make it work you should create your custom.css and override bootstrap's css like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>form>a, {
    color: #777;
   /* other styles */
}
```

Also there is easier way: wrap your `div` with class `.navbar` by `<h:form>`.
And the problem with selectors will be solved.

```
       <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<h:form>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Home.xhtml">MyFacebook</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Home.xhtml">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Posts.xhtml">Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Login.xhtml">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/WebEng_P07/faces/Register.xhtml">Registrierung</a></li>
                    <li> 
                        <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}"   rendered="#   {loginBean.loggedIn}">
                        </h:commandLink>    
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I do not understand the second solution? I wrapped my navbar with a h:form but now noting will be styled anymore?

Comment: ahh my bad i had a problem with the css import now everything works fine ty for your help :)